# In linear regression, i am getting NAN values for cost and weights

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression

```
    import numpy as np
    def cost_function(X,Y,B):
       J = np.sum((X.T.dot(B)-Y) ** 2) / (2 * len(Y))
       return J
    def gradient_descent(X,Y,B,alpha,iterations): 
        cost_history = [0] * iterations    
        for iteration in range(iterations):  
            h = X.T.dot(B)
            loss = h - Y
            gradient = X.dot(loss) / len(Y)
            B = B + (alpha * gradient)
            cost = cost_function(X,Y,B)
            cost_history[iteration] = cost
        return B,cost_history
```

B--weights (2,1)
X--input(2,700)
Y--output(700,1)
alpha--learning rate (0.001)
iterations -- 3000
i am using cost function to calculate the error

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Note that dividing the error by a constant in the cost function is unnecessary, so you do not need the "/ (2 * len(Y)"  as "len(Y)" will give the same value each time any individual regression is run.

Comment: It might be useful if you make a simple example that is to fit a straight line using only three or four data points, that is easier for you to debug. If you cannot get that simple code to work without error, then please edit your question to use that simpler code with the few data points included.